# Display pages and posts in archive

Tags: php, wordpress

I have many categories, but for clearity I will do an example with only two:

- **News** that contains many **posts**
- **Products** that contains many **pages** (I've added this feature in `functions.php`)

I want that `archive.php` displays:

- the posts when the user choose the category News
- the pages when the user choose the category Products

At the moment Wordpress by deafult shows only posts and not pages.

I know that this is possible by adding a simple function in `functions.php` but I can't find it.

**EDIT**: For another project with custom post type "Books" I used this code

```
function query_post_type($query) {
    $post_types = get_post_types();

    if ( is_category() || is_tag()) {

        $post_type = get_query_var('books');

        if ( $post_type ) {
            $post_type = $post_type;
        } else {
            $post_type = $post_types;
        }

        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type ); 


        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
```

Is there something like that for my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can query for solely pages in the WP Query.

PHP:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This will return all pages in your database, and zero posts. Vice versa, you could have `'post_type' => 'post'` to query all posts, but that's the default behaviour of the WP Query.

For more documentation on this, check out the [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) reference in the Wordpress Codex.

Comment: I have a single archive.php that works for all categories. Also, I can not specify the category to query. See the edit in first post.